# What is the word for working hard to "take the concerns of someone away"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have someone who is concerned about my lack of experience on the job I might be hired to do.

How can I reply back saying that I will work hard to "get rid of their concerns" or "make these concerns go away"?

Thanks!

Comment: You will work hard to ***alleviate*** their concerns.

Comment: *Console, condole, soothe, encourage, give solace...*

Comment: encourage? How would that be used in a sentence?

Comment: @Jim: You'd [actually be more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alleviate+their+concerns%2Callay+their+concerns&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calleviate%20their%20concerns%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Callay%20their%20concerns%3B%2Cc0) to ***allay** their concerns* rather than *alleviate* them. But I'm surprised to discover how recently both versions have gained traction, particularly bearing in mind that...

Comment: ...overall use of ***alleviate*** is increasing, whereas relatively speaking, ***allay*** is [going down the pan](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alleviate%2Callay&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calleviate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Callay%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You [*put their minds at rest*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&biw=990&bih=694&q=idiom+put+your+mind+at+rest).

This is a common idiom to suggest that you will prove to them that they need not exercise their minds with worry.

Comment: Also expressed as 'put your minds at ease'.

Answer (score 12):

Assuage

verb (used with object),

assuaged, assuaging.

to make milder or less severe; relieve; ease; mitigate:
"to assuage one's grief; to assuage one's pain."

to appease; satisfy; allay; relieve:
"to assuage one's hunger."

to soothe, calm, or mollify:
"to assuage his fears; to assuage her anger."

Via dictionary.com [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assuage?s=t)

Comment: If you added a textual reference to the source of your definition and a link, I would upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bib. I just go that info off of the google search results page. I've cleaned it up and cited the dictionary.

Comment: +1 Thanks. You might want to check out *onelook.com*. It's a site that searches a number of online dictionaries, many very good. From that portal, you can view several definitions quickly.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to eliminate their concerns rather than merely make them less concerning then I would suggest that you work to **Dispel** their concerns.

[Merriam Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispel)

> to drive away by or as if by scattering

Example sentences, also from Merriam Webster:

> This report should dispel any doubts you have about the plan.
>
> She made an official statement to dispel any rumors about her
>   retirement.
>
> The experience dispelled some of our fears about the process.

Answer (score 0):

To my ear " allay your fears" sounds like the correct phrase.

Comment: I agree that this phrase is frequently used to express the idea that the poster has in mind. To make your answer more complete and self-contained—and more helpful to readers who may not be well acquainted with the word _allay_, please consider adding the relevant definition of _allay_ to your answer, citing (and linking, if possible) to a suitable dictionary.